# Grep IP Range Bash Script

Tags: bash, networking, scripting, range, ip

I just got into Bash scripting and I'm having a hard time grepping a specific IP range from a file.

I've tried the following:

```
grep "213.184.111.[128][254]" example.txt
```

Is there an easier way using `seq` or `sort`?

Comment: That command is not grepping for a range. At least, not a contiguous range, but the set of IPs that end in something included in the set [12, 15, 14, 22, 25, 24, 82, 85, 84]

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of lines from `example.txt` (includes lines that do and do not match your search requirement); also update the question to show the expected results (corresponding to the sample you provide)

Answer (score 1):

When `awk` is also possible. Use `.` as field separator and compare fourth field.

```
awk -v start=128 -v end=254 -v FS=. '$4>=start && $4<=end' example.txt
```

Output:

```
213.184.111.128
213.184.111.129
213.184.111.130
...
213.184.111.252
213.184.111.253
213.184.111.254
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

My colleague just helped me out with the following:

```
grep -P "(213\.184\.111\.(12[8-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]))"
```

Is there an easier option?

Comment: close; this will match on `*.255`

Comment: Alternative: `grep -E "213.184.111.($(echo {128..254} | tr ' ' '|'))" example.txt`. This alternative is ugly, `awk` is better.

Comment: Regular expressions are designed for matching textual patterns, not numeric patterns. As you're discovering, a numeric pattern generally can be expressed as a textual pattern, but it's usually pretty ugly.